# How to better understand `remote_side` in sqlalchemy?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I've been studying sqlalchemy's self referential table. I've read the documentation many times and still have difficulties understanding the concept of `remote_side`. Could someone please draw a diagram or use an analogy to help explain this concept? I think visualizing is a better way but anything helps would be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: By the way, in my opinion the word `remote` is a little vague, as it can be interpreted from different angles. Like the word `left` and `rigt`, it really depends on which direction you are facing, my `right` could be your `left`. I'm not really confident in this but I would guess chaing the name from `remote_side` to `many_side` may help? Correct me if I'm wrong here.

Comment: Remote, as in remote to this relationship, vs. local as in where this relationship is defined.

Answer (score 8):

When specifying a relationship between two tables, one of the tables has a *foreign key*. This foreign key "marks" one or more columns as being "connected" to columns in another table.

When specifying relationships in SQLAlchemy, we're using the term "remote" when talking about the columns "on the other side" of the foreign-key columns. Or, whichever columns the "foreign" columns are "linked to".

For example, consider a "Customer" table with a "Order" table:

```
+---------------+         +------------------+
|  Customer     |         | Order            |
+---------------+         +------------------+
|  customer-id  | ------- | customer_id [FK] |
|  name         |         | order_id         |
+---------------+         +------------------+
```

Assume the *order* table has a relationship with the *customer* table via the *customer_id* column.

In that case, the *foreign key* will be located on the *Order* table, and it will "point to" the *Customer.customer_id* column.

As we established earlier, the "remote side" in SQLAlchemy is the "other side" of the foreign key.

So in this particular example, the "remote side" is the *Customer.customer_id* column.

When working with self-referential tables the concept is the same. You have some columns defined as foreign keys "pointing to" other columns (but in the same table this time). But the concept of "foreign" and "remote" remains the same for SA. You just have to adapt it as necessary for the self-referential relationship.

Answer (score 3):

Since no one seems to be interested in such a beginner's concept, I will try my best to attack this.

First visualize two identical tables, one on the left and the other on the right. Now take a deep breath.

By specifying `remote_side` to the attribute that the foreign key refering to, you actually establishing a relationship that from the local to the remote.

Now the question is, can I specify the `remote_side` to the foreign key attribute itself? Let us see the difference by doing an experiment:

```
class Employee(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'employees'
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    manager_id = Column(Integer(), ForeignKey('employees.id'))
    name = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    Manager = relationship("Employee", backref=backref('reports'), remote_side=[manager_id])
```

Running this, we get this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Employee.Manager and back-reference Employee.reports are both of the same direction symbol('ONETOMANY').  Did you mean to set `remote_side` on the many-to-one side?
```

So apparently, this doesn't work. We are locked in a one-way tyranny.

Comment: If you are gonna vote down my answer please share some of your thoughts, don't just ignore it, come on!

Comment: [`remote_side=[id]`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/self_referential.html), if you want many-to-one. `reports = relationship('Employee', backref=backref('Manager', remote_side=[id]))`, if you want one-to-many, with a many-to-one backref. It is somewhat unclear what this answer is about. Why do you want to define the foreign key as the remote as well? That goes against what a foreign key is.

Comment: Did you mean that it should work so that if you define a foreign key as remote, it'd form a one-to-many, where the referenced key is the local and the foreign key the remote? That's what SQLAlchemy assumes, if you just skip defining the remote side.